# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, even though cors is enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, xampp

I'm creating a web server on my raspberry pi, on which I'm hosting a website for plant water control in node.js and a database. It works like this:
Node.js connects to the database and displays all items in a table. When the user interacts with the table, by clicking on a td elemnt and modifies it, this gets sent to the database, if it's in the correct format. This works on the raspberry pi localhost:3000, but when I connect to it with my computer, I get these errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OvqJ4FV' from origin 'http://192.168.0.101:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
manager.js:108 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OvqJ4FV net::ERR_FAILED
value @ polling.js:298
i @ polling.js:237
value @ polling.js:190
value @ polling.js:215
value @ polling.js:96
value @ polling.js:56
value @ transport.js:46
value @ socket.js:170
a @ socket.js:111
value @ manager.js:108
(anonymous) @ manager.js:328
Show 9 more frames
Show less
```

This is the main.cjs file:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
var mysql = require('mysql2');

var plantData = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: "plants",
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0
});

const app = express();

const cors = require("cors");
const port2 = 5110;

app.listen(port2);
console.log("" + 3000);

app.use("*", cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
var io = socketIo(server);

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", "src2");

app.use(express.static("src2"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("ejs/main.ejs");
  res.setHeader("Allow-Access-Control-Header", "*");
});
var howManyPlants = 0;

app.get("/plants", (req, res) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      plantData.query("SELECT * FROM `plants` order by id asc"
        , (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            resolve(results);
          }
          var plants = results;
          //res.setHeader("Allow-Access-Control-Header", "*");
          res.json(plants);
          
          howManyPlants = plants.length;
        });
    });
});

app.get("/maxPlantId", (req, res) => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    plantData.query(`Select max(id) from plants`, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        resolve(results);

        plantIdNow = res.json(results);
      }
    });
  });
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("setAllPlantsTime", (time) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("1");
      plantData.query(`UPDATE plants set plantTime = "${time}"`, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
  });
  });

  socket.on("changePlantProperty", (property) => {
    var plantId = property.id;
    var plantProperty = property.property;
    var plantPropertyValue = property.value;

    console.log(plantId + " " + plantProperty + " " + plantPropertyValue);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      plantData.query(`UPDATE plants set ${plantProperty} = "${plantPropertyValue}" where id = ${plantId}`, (err, results) => {
        console.log(`UPDATE plants set ${plantProperty} = "${plantPropertyValue}" where id = ${plantId}`);
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  socket.on("deletePlant", (plantId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      plantData.query(`Delete from plants where id = ${plantId}`, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  socket.on("createPlant", (plantInput) => {
    var plantId = plantInput.id;
    var plantTime = plantInput.plantTime;
    var plantWeekDays = plantInput.plantWeekDays;
    var plantWater = plantInput.plantWater;

    console.log(plantId + " " + plantTime + " " + plantWeekDays + " " + plantWater);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      plantData.query(`INSERT INTO plants VALUES ('` + plantId +`','` + plantTime + `','` + plantWeekDays + `','` + plantWater + `')`, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('disconnected');
  });
});

module.exports = {
  io
}
```

I have tried diffrent tutorials, but none of them worked. I use xampp.

Comment: your express app listens on port 5110 - that's where you've setup CORS ... the error shows the issue is on port 3000 - there's no evidence of CORS responses being set up on that port

Comment: Also, why is your client using `/socket.io` as the path for the URL? and what does XAMPP have to do with it? Your nodejs code is the server (on two different ports) is it not? There's no indication of any Apache, MariaDB, PHP or Perl in your question/code

Comment: Should I use server.use(cors())?

Comment: When I connect to http://192.168.0.133:5110/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ovso6u3 I get: Cannot GET /socket.io/, when i connect to http://192.168.0.133:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ovso6u3, I get: 0{"sid":"1rrDwaX8x42Gcu6nAABB","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000}. So the 3000 is set up correctly, but I don't know how to enable cors on the http server.

Comment: I also get this error: localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ovsoyj4:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
manager.js:108 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ovso-Vr net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED